# How do you update an already persisted entity with Panache?

Tags: quarkus

I am writing a JaxRS resource in quarkus with panache and I have noticed that I couldn't get a PUT/PATCH request to work.  More specifically I can't seem to update a previously persisted entity in the database.  I figured I was doing something wrong, but then I tried the the quarkus-quickstart for panache which can be found [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/hibernate-orm-panache-resteasy), and I noticed that the [PUT](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/master/hibernate-orm-panache-resteasy/src/main/java/com/acme/hibernate/orm/panache/FruitResource.java#L59) doesn't work there either.

What it does is that it gets an entity using the `findById` method, changes that entity, and then just returns that changed entity.  But it doesn't actually change it in the database.  For the quickstart I set up the database using docker as it suggests in the README.

What is the recommended way for updating an already persisted Panache entity?

#### Example Request Flow

These are the requests and responses I got with the quarkus quickstart:

1. `GET` localhost:8080/fruits.

   - Response:`[ {"persistent": true, "id": 1, "name": "Cherry"} ]`
2. `PUT` localhost:8080/fruits/1, body: `{ "name": "edited name" }`

   - Response: `{ "persistent": false, "id": 1, "name": "edited name" }`
3. `GET` localhost:8080/fruits

   - Response:`[ {"persistent": true, "id": 1, "name": "Cherry"} ]`

Comment: this looks like related to some issues of Panache which were just resolved in master, and some others which are being worked on this week. I'd suggest to try version 0.13.0 once it's released.

Comment: Or you could always build from `master` to give it a spin :wink:

Comment: I confirm that it is a bug in 0.12.0. It's fixed in master and the upcoming 0.13.0 fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can close this question with "I confirm that it is a bug in 0.12.0. It's fixed in master and the upcoming 0.13.0 fixes it. " from comment.